# Unable to remove class after using toggle class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, navigation

I have three navigations in one page and I'm trying to show the active links for each nav. For some reason the third nav isn't working correctly. For example, if you click on "chapter 2" or "chapter 3" or "chapter 4", "chapter 1" stays active. I don't know if it's because "Chapter 1" and "sublink4" from the middle nav have the same url. I tried removing the active class of the third nav, but it's not working. Unfortunately the snipping isn't working as it is on my computer. I only used target="_blank" on the snippet, not only my local machine since you can't click on links on the snippet without restarting the snippet.Thanks

[image]

```js
$(window).on('load', function () {
    $('body').setActiveMenuItem();
    $('body').setActiveMenuItem2();
    $('body').setActiveMenuItem3();
});

$(document).ready(function () {

    //first nav
    $.fn.setActiveMenuItem2 = function () {

        $.each($('.nav1').find('li'), function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('active',
                window.location.pathname.indexOf($(this).find('a').attr('href')) > -1);
        });

    }

    //middle nav
    $.fn.setActiveMenuItem3 = function () {

        $.each($('.nav3').find('li'), function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('active3',
                window.location.pathname.indexOf($(this).find('a').attr('href')) > -1);
        });

    }

    //third nav 
    $.fn.setActiveMenuItem = function () {

        $.each($('.nav2').find('li'), function () {

            $(this).removeClass('active2');

            $(this).toggleClass('active2',
                window.location.pathname.indexOf($(this).find('a').attr('href')) > -1);
        });
    }
});
```

```css
li.active {
    background-color: red;
}
li.active2 {
    background-color: blue;
}
li.active {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.nav1 ul, .nav3 ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
nav {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
}
li {
    list-style: none;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    padding: 10px;
}
li a {
    padding: 10px;
}
li a:hover {
    color: red;
    background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
      <nav class="nav1">
          <ul>
             <li>  <a href="/link-1" target="_blank">Link 1</a>  </li>
             <li><a href="/link-2" target="_blank" >Link 2</a> </li>
             <li><a href="/link-3" target="_blank">Link 3</a> </li>
             <li><a href="/link-4" target="_blank">Link 4</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

        <nav class="nav3">
          <ul>
              <li><a href="/link-1/sublink-1" target="_blank">Subink 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="/link-2/sublink-2" target="_blank">Subink 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="/link-2/sublink-3" target="_blank">Subink 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

        <nav class="nav2">
          <ul>
              <li><a href="/link-1/sublink-1/chapter-1" target="_blank">Chapter 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="/link-1/sublink-1/chapter-2" target="_blank">Chapter 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="/link-1/sublink-1/chapter-3" target="_blank">Chapter 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you add some HTML snippets to it?

Comment: The removeClass does nothing if you immediately call `toggleClass(class, state)` afterwards

Comment: @SumitRidhal unfortunately I cannot replicate what I have on a snippet because clicking on a ink would refresh the snippet's page.

Comment: @freedomn-m I just placed it immediately after toggleClass(class, state) and it didn't fix it, so where do I place it?

Comment: @Charly set `target="_blank"` and try.

Comment: Why do you think you need the `removeClass` line at all?

Comment: @SumitRidhal I just added a snippet. Thanks!

Comment: @freedomn-m that's the only solution i could think of. What do yo suggest?

Answer (score 0):

-> replace $ to j Query

->Either replace a latest jquery

Comment: Use to find closest li on click

Answer (score 0):

Use `preventDefault` to let default event handler to open new link.
`window.open()` will let you open links in new tabs.

#### Note: This code won't work in sand-boxes.

Let me know if I'm missing something?

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
links.forEach((node) => {
  node.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.target.classList.add('active');
    window.open(evt.target.href);
  });
});
```

```css
li.active {
  background-color: red;
}

li.active2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

li.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.nav1 ul,
.nav3 ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

nav {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  padding: 10px;
}

li a {
  padding: 10px;
}

li a:hover {
  color: red;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav class="nav1">
    <ul>
      <li> <a href="/link-1" target="_blank">Link 1</a> </li>
      <li><a href="/link-2" target="_blank">Link 2</a> </li>
      <li><a href="/link-3" target="_blank">Link 3</a> </li>
      <li><a href="/link-4" target="_blank">Link 4</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <nav class="nav3">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/link-1/sublink-1" target="_blank">Subink 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="/link-2/sublink-2" target="_blank">Subink 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="/link-2/sublink-3" target="_blank">Subink 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <nav class="nav2">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/link-1/sublink-1/chapter-1" target="_blank">Chapter 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="/link-1/sublink-1/chapter-2" target="_blank">Chapter 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="/link-1/sublink-1/chapter-3" target="_blank">Chapter 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work :(. Outside that snippet i don't need target="_blank" because i want the links to open on the same page. Also on the snippet all the links stay active when clicking on another link, just like my current issue. Please help.